# How to override "Create @bundlename" text?

Tags: 7, string-overrides

I'm using [String Overrides](https://www.drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) module to override some strings on my site. I could override some strings like

"**Performance**" to "**Clear**"   (`admin/config/development/performance`)

"**Content**" to "**List of Nodes**" (`admin/content`)

But it doesn't override "**Create @bundlename**" strings like

"**Create Article**" to "**New Article**".

[image]

When I navigate to `/node/add/article` it's still showing **Create Article** as title of the 'Node add form'.

I've cleared cache, but still not working.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using [Node Add title](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_add_title) module ...

> Above module allows you to configure the title of the Node Add pages
>   and the Node Editing pages.
>
> The default title of the page where users create new nodes is
>   constructed by Drupal in a dynamic way that not always looks good. By
>   default Drupal concatenates the word Create and the name of the
>   content type. The result could be something like "Create Basic page"
>   or "Create article". This is not always acceptable.
>
> With this little module you can replace Drupal's default concatenated
>   Node Add page title and the Node Editing page title with a title of
>   your choice for every content type.
>
> After installing this module you will see the following two new fields
>   at the bottom of the content type configuration form:
>
> Node Add page title Node Edit page title Use these two new fields for
>   overriding the titles of the new node creation pages and the node
>   editing pages.

PS : Module is in Dev Version.... Test before you use..

If you are interested to change same using code you can use [drupal_set_title](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_set_title/7)

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
    if($form_id == 'mynodetype_node_form'){
         drupal_set_title('My new title');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Anil, The module works great! I can use coding but client wants user interface for that so I had to install this module . both ways helpful. Thanks for the alternate module :)

Answer (score 1):

For those who may be looking to override the string for node creation using string override, you need to use the following under Original : "Create @name"

Answer (score 0):

This is the reason why it doesn't work the way you want it to.  StringOverrides uses the localization functions, and the localization functions do not translate @params.

Answer (score 0):

In `original Column` write `"Create @bundlename"`. In `Replacement Column` write `"New @bundlename"`.

Note : This will override for all the Bundles.

Comment: I think I already tried that but didn't work. Did you check it?